# Disk boot failed, insert system disk and press enter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, debian

I tried booting a server that I built with :

- multiple usb sticks
- different images (distro and version Desktop Server)
- I'm using balenaEtcher on MacOS to burn my images

what I've done in chronological order :

- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Server on Usb stick 1 : failed
- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Server on Usb stick 2 : failed
- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Server on Usb stick 1 on my Mac : succeeded
- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on Usb stick 1 : succeeded twice in a row but I had to interrupt the process because it ran too slow (keyboard not repsonding for a minute then OK for 10 seconds and repeat process)
- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on Usb stick 1 : failed
- Testing ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on Usb stick 2 : failed
- Testing Debian netinst on Usb stick 1 : failed
- Testing Debian netinst on Usb stick 2 : failed
  Now using Live Linux Usb Creator on a windows VM on my mac:
  *
- Testing freshly downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 Server on known-good usb stick 3 : failed

I checked Ubuntu server image by following ubuntu tutorial on the subject.
I could install Debian on another computer with no problem.

I have very few BIOS settings to tinkle with so I don't think that's the problem.

I don't know what else to try.

Edit : Well I tried Ubuntu Desktop/debian on USB stick 3 and it worked. Still I don't know why it refused to boot on Ubuntu server.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a hardware failure? This is question is attracting close votes as it is a bit light on debugging details. Please see [ask] and take our [tour] to improve your question.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with the question? I clicked your link and still think my question isn't bad. Also I don't know what to add as debugging details since all I got from the computer was the message in the title.

Comment: You would at least need to provide some details about the hardware of the "server", i.e. manufacturer, mainboard model, which BIOS settings you have available (since you write you have few) etc.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer : the 2 first USB sticks were detected on other computers but not this one. Second thing is that you have to directly go to bios setup > Hard Disk priority > and put the usb key in first place. If it doesn't appear then change your usb key it's not compatible.

Part of my problem was that I had to put it in first priority otherwise it wouldn't work.

Edit : I still haven't found why it wouldn't boot on a Ubuntu Server image.